# Pick Commits from different branches into main branch

Tags: git

I have 3 branches:
 - master 
 - feature1
 - feature2

Feature1 & Feature2 have common code which is independent and has several commits, How do i pick individual commits from f1 and f2 into master?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git cherry-pick`.  For example, if you wanted to copy a commit from `feature1` whose hash was `a43kbjhl` to `master`, you could do the following:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick a43kbjhl
```

And you can repeat the above step for all the commits you want to cherry pick.  Keep in mind that if you actual inspect the commits you have copied over, their SHA-1 hashes actually won't match the originals.  This is because Git has created *new* commits for each cherry-pick.

Comment: yes, it solves my problem. I can cherry-pick with SHA for each commit while on my master branch. Thanks Tim